# PhP e-mail auto e-mail response

Tags: php, email, auto-responder

On my website we have a promotion going on where users input their name and e-mail and then we send them an e-mail with the same title, same text and an the voucher image at the end embedded/inserted onto the e-mail (not attached).

We thought we would be able to copy paste easily but over the past 6 weeks we have sent out over 1000 e-mails and this is undo able any more.

We have a php code that simply sends us their info.
Does anyone know what to add at the end of the php so that when someone inputs their e-mail and name we can just automatically send an e-mail to them with the "template" title, text and image?

I have tried many different things but most programmes are newsletter senders not auto-responders. Can't use gmail auto response either because we receive other e-mails for different things as well. We don't want to send the promo to everyone who e-mails us.

Any help?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Check **Github** for **sendemail** repository. It allows you to send emails through php. What you can do is that you can set **sendemail** repository in your project then whenever someone enter an email id run a php script.For configuring **sendemail** everything is provided on **Github**.

**Link:** https://github.com/mogaal/sendemail

Script will look something like this:

```
$message = "Thank you for your interest. We will get back to you as soon as possible.<br />Sincerely,<br />(My Name)";
$subject = "Confirmation";

$headers2 = "From: $webMaster\r\n";
$headers2 .= "Content-type:  text/html\r\n";
mail($leademail, $subject, $message, $headers2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample script you can use without any third party classes.

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

You can add html content to the $message variable

Comment: Thanks for that @cybertoy. Quick question,


$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


What does that mean? And what would I have to change around?

Comment: Those are E-mail headers. Just put your from E-mail address and reply to address for that. I strongly recommend you to follow some basic tutorials about PHP mail function.